# Downloading kmz/shapefile of differences between 2 compared image dates from planet.com?

Tags: differences, planet

I'm interested in downloading a KMZ or shapefile of the difference feature when you compare days on planet.com.  The images are huge composites so I don't think downloading 7,000 items for each date and then using difference function in ArcMap is feasible.

[image: Like this]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. What have you tried so far?  Can you add some more detail on what you have tried so far and exactly what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hello, I've tried searching  through Planet's faqs and google.  I don't see anyplace to obtain the data that's produced.  Its possible that the functionality is disabled to users.  I did send a query to Planet as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to download the differences since they are all computed on the client side from the tiles that are shown in the browser.

Comment: I figured as much but thought I should ask, just in case.  Thank you.

Comment: For reference of anyone else who comes across this: basemaps of monthly composites are for pay and not available to download at full resolution through a free account.